# Mockito Inject mock into Spy object

Tags: mockito, junit5

```
Class A {
    B b;  
    C c;  
}

Class C {
    D d;  
    E e;  
}
```

I want to write unit test for A but I do not want to mock methods of C. However, I do want to mock D and E in C.

I have tried these options:
Option 1:

```
@Mock B b;  
@Mock D d;  
@Mock E e;  
@Spy @InjectMocks C c;  
@InjectMocks A a;
```

Option 2:

```
@Mock B b;  
@Mock D d;  
@Mock E e;   
@Spy C c = Mockito.spy(new C(d,e));  
@InjectMocks A a;
```

Option 3:
suggestions in [Mockito Inject mock into Spy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926636/mockito-inject-mock-into-spy-object)

None of the options are working for me. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: `new A(new B(), new C(mock(D.class, E.class))` – how do you inject the dependencies into your classes?

Comment: Currently, I am doing field injection by using InjectMocks

Comment: Mock injection runs after initialization of the class. When a field is assigned in the field initializer, the mocks don't exist yet. Read up on "pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference" and probably also [Why is my class not calling my mocked methods in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968), which could be applied here (but not an exact dupe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my class not calling my mocked methods in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-is-my-class-not-calling-my-mocked-methods-in-unit-test) (it's a dupe now)