# How to @InjectMock an dependency inside an @Spy in JUnit 5, Mockito and SprintBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock dependencies inside my Spy object but mockito is not able to inject the mock objects as I am getting NullPointerException inside the Spy object.

My code is as follows:

```
@Component()
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Target implements Target<InputPojo> {

    private final TargetHelper<InputPojo> inputHelper;

    @Override
    public List<ProcessedPojo> testMethod(List<InputPojo> inputs) throws someException {
        inputHelper.process(inputs);
         // ...further processing ...
        return processedList;
    }
}

@Component()
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class MyTargetHelper implements TargetHelper<InputPojo> {

    private final Map<SomeEnum, Double> someMap;

    private final AlertService alertService;

    private final DatabaseService databaseService;

    @Override
    public void process(List<InputPojo> inputs) throws SomeException {
        try {
            for (InputPojo i : inputs) {
                furtherProcess(databaseService.fetchForId(i.getId())); // Null pointer exception
            }
        } catch (SomeOtherException e) {
            alertService.raiseAlert("database error");
            throw(new SomeException());
        }
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TargetTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Target target;

    @Mock
    DatabaseService databaseService;

    @Mock
    AlertService alertService;

    @Spy
    Map<SomeEnum, Double> someMap = new EnumMap<>(SomeEnum.class);

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    MyTargetHelper inputHelper = new MyTargetHelper(someMap, alertService, databaseService);

    static final List<InputPojo> inputs;

    static {
        // add values to inputs and someMap
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void testTarget() {
        when(databaseService.fetchForId(anyString())).thenReturn("fetch success");

        target.testMethod(inputs);
    }
}
```

I have tried every other related question but none of them could solve my issue.
I also tried changing

```
   private final TargetHelper<InputPojo> inputHelper;
```

to

```
   private final MyTargetHelper inputHelper;
```

but it didn't help. I have tried

- [Mockito Inject mock into Spy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926636/mockito-inject-mock-into-spy-object)
  (except the Accepted Answer as I am already Autowiring dependencies instead of @Inject)

I need to run Helper as part of my unit test in order to properly verify results of the TargetMethod, hence I want to Spy the method, however, I will need to mock the database service and alert service in order to make HelperMethod work properly.

Comment: have you tried programmatically creating the mocks? Something like this:
`someMap = Mokito.mock(AlertService.class);
databaseService = Mokito.mock(DatabaseService.class);`
Also, for data is better to use a real object and not a mock, therefore ` Map<SomeEnum, Double> someMap` can be an actual map with some data for testing,

Comment: Yes, for data like `someMap` I am making the actual Map. This map is configured as a bean and autowired by spring during actual run hence it is a dependency in the helper class. I need to inject this as dependency hence I am using @Spy on `someMap`. I didn't try making mocks proogramatically, let me try that as well and update here on the results.

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir Thanks, it magically worked! I wonder why Exactly the same code didn't work with Annotations while it worked programattically. However, one weird thing I observed here, while running the tests with coverage, none of the Lines of MyTargetHelper were shown as covered while during runtime, those lines were actually executed. Any pointers on this?

Comment: i am not sure, maybe it is not clear to mockito where to inject the mock or maybe you cannot inject mocks into a spy (just an assumption).
by the way, have you considered trying to use the real `MyTargetHelper` and only mock his dependencies? basically to remove the `@Spy` annotation? To inject it you can just pass it as a constructor argument, the same as you did when creating the `inputHelper `